# Spark PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to return a `double` type from a `udf` in `spark`, but it gives me this error.

The `udf` is:

```
def new_pagerank(links, current_pr, counters):
  n_pr = 0;
  #for each incoming link to the page calculate the pagerank
  #zip the links and counters to get them both in the loop
  for l, c in zip(links, counters):
    
    
    #get current_pr of the link l
    current_link_pr=current_pr.loc[current_pr['id'] == l].PR

    n_pr += current_link_pr/c
  new_pr = 0.85/N+0.15*n_pr
  return new_pr
```

the `udf` caller is:

```
new_pagerank_udf = udf(lambda x,y: new_pagerank(x,pageRankPDF,y), DoubleType())

NewPageRankDF=ReverseDF.select(ReverseDF["id"],new_pagerank_udf(ReverseDF["links"],ReverseDF["counters"]).alias("PR"))
pagerankPDF=NewPageRankDF.toPandas()
```

ReverseDF:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Links: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- counters: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

pageRankPDF:

```
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   id      5319 non-null   int64  
 1   PR      5319 non-null   float64
```

the problem is that `current_link_pr` returns a `series` and not a `float` type but i cannot cast to it using `.iloc[0]`

```
current_link_pr=current_pr.loc[current_pr['id'] == l].PR.iloc[0]
```

because it gives `'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'`

So is there a way to cast it to a `float` without using `loc()`?